# How to convert JSON string to Class with Newtonsoft while ignoring named json sub objects

Tags: c#, json, razor, json.net, .net-6.0

Im not sure exactly the right phrasing to as this question but here is the problem. I'm getting data from CoinMarketCap and trying to convert its json response into a Object.  My class looks like this:

```
namespace CryptoCharter.CoinMarketCap
{
    public class LatestQuotes
    {
        public List<LatestQuote> Data { get; set; }
    }
    public class LatestQuote
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With my Deserialize call looking like this:

```
LatestQuotes latestQuote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatestQuotes>(data);
```

Unfortunately the problem i have is that the json return is like this:

```
{
  "status": {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-14T18:52:04.589Z",
  },
  "data": {
    "BTC": {
      "name": "aozn4bq7ss",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "slug": "7sh2jotqs8q",
    },
    "ETH": {
      "name": "4x98y18ibem",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "slug": "nibbc2nhejg",
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is how do I get around the fact that data has more json in it. Is there a way to get newtonsoft to treat it as if it looks like this:

```
{
  "status": {
    "timestamp": "2022-07-14T18:52:04.589Z",
  },
  "data": [
      {"name": "aozn4bq7ss",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "slug": "7sh2jotqs8q",
    },
    {
      "name": "4x98y18ibem",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "slug": "nibbc2nhejg",
    }
  ]  
}
```

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this since the list of items could be any size I can't just assume BTC and ETH are always there and what others will be.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest deserialising the json to a dedicated class and then picking out what you need.

The model:

```
public class LatestQuotesResponseDto
{
   public Dictionary<string,LatestQuote> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
// TODO error handling
var deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatestQuotesResponseDto>(data);

var latestQuotes = new LatestQuotes
{
    Data = deserialised.Data.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The solution was using the Dictionary class. i didn't realize you could do that. Thanks for the thelp.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

    LatestQuotes latestQuotes = new LatestQuotes { 
           Timestamp = (DateTime)jsonParsed["status"]["timestamp"] };

    if (jsonParsed["data"].Type.ToString() == "Array") 
       latestQuotes.Data = jsonParsed["data"].ToObject<List<LatestQuote>>();
        else latestQuotes.Data = ((JObject)jsonParsed["data"]).Properties()
                .Select(e => e.Value.ToObject<LatestQuote>()).ToList();

public class LatestQuotes
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<LatestQuote> Data { get; set; }
}
```